# Flipclock.js обратный отсчет

Tags: javascript

Как в плагине flipclock.js установить таймер обратного отсчета?
В документации не нашел этого пункта, возможно у кого то есть готовое решение?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), {});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Я у себя так запускал, надеюсь поможет)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var clock;
   var futureDate = new Date("May 29, 2016 0:00 PM EDT");
   var currentDate = new Date();
   var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;

   function dayDiff(first, second) {
     return (second - first) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
   }
   if (dayDiff(currentDate, futureDate) < 100) {
     $('.clock').addClass('twoDayDigits');
   } else {
     $('.clock').addClass('threeDayDigits');
   }
   if (diff < 0) {
     diff = 0;
   }
   clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
     clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
     language: 'ru',
     countdown: true
   });
 });
```

[рабочий пример на Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/31azsDhMcCbPZj04Vyu2?p=preview)

Comment: (index):45 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).FlipClock is not a function

Comment: @ads смотри пример на планкере, все работает

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример

```
// Instantiate a coutdown FlipClock
clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    clockFaceOptions: {
        countdown: true
    }
});
clock.setCountdown(true);
clock.face.on('stop', function() {
    // add 24 hours worth of seconds to the clock face
    clock.setFaceValue(24 * 60 * 60);
    clock.start();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v66j6r5j/ он конечно сильно кастомизирован, но думаю вы легко найдете что вам надо.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: diff is not defined

Comment: @asd я же дал ссылку на пример, var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;